# Next JS "revalidate" does not "revalidate"

Tags: javascript, next.js

My code on the dev server

```
function Home(props) {
  console.log("Hello")
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.user.map((user) => (
        <li key={user.id}>{user.email}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default Home

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  const data = await res.json()

  return {
    props: {
      user: data,
    },
    revalidate: 10,
  }
}
```

Then I run *npm run build* and start the real server with *npm run start*

Now if I change my JSX from

```
<li key={user.id}>{user.email}</li>
```

to

```
<li key={user.id}>{user.username}</li>
```

And wait some time, then the page still looks like before, nothing has changed -> It still shows user.email and not user.username

Comment: That's not how incremental static regeneration works. The `revalidate` property is meant for the data you return in `getStaticProps`, not for changing the client code itself. Running the app in production mode then trying to modify the source code will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reload you page to see your changes , Because `Next js` caches `HTML` on the server and won't show the fresh data to the user as soon as it updates .

Comment: I tried, even in a different browser but it does not work

Comment: try deleting `.next` folder and running `next build  ` after removing

Comment: Yes now it gets re generated (logs "Hello" in the console) but still with old data. So no, it does not work.